# How do I map *, so after each recurrent press, it expands its selection one word over?

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, search

For example:

```
QString QSSMLTools::heather(QString s)
{
    if (!m_Enable) {return s;}

    s.insert(0,"<voice name='Heather'>");
    s.append("</voice>");
    return s;
}
QString QSSMLTools::isabella(QString s)
{
    if (!m_Enable) {return s;}

    s.insert(0,"<voice name='Isabella'>");
    s.append("</voice>");
    return s;
}
```

Placing my cursor over `v` on `s.insert(0,"<oice name='Heather'>");`
 and pressing <kbd>*</kbd> will give me , highlighting 4 selections:

```
s.insert(0,"< name='Heather'>");
s.append("</>");
s.insert(0,"< name='Isabella'>");
s.append("</>");
```

Pressing <kbd>**</kbd> should give me `voice name` highlighting two sections.

Pressing <kbd>***</kbd> should give me `voice name='` highlighting two sections.

Pressing <kbd>****</kbd> should give me `voice name='Heather` highlighting one section.

How can this behaviour be achieved?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with two mappings, a normal mode mapping, and a visual mode mapping. Try this:

```
nnoremap * viw
xnoremap * wiw
```

The first one is pretty straightforward. It starts visual mode (`v`), and selects (i)nside of the current (w)ord. Then, the second time you hit it, the other mapping applies since we will no longer be in normal mode.

So on the second press, it moves forward one word, (now the selection is `voice n`) then again, selects (i)nside of the current (w)ord. Now the selection is `voice name`. Hitting it the third and fourth times repeats the same concept, and can even extend across multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to highlight every occurence of the selected words. You can easily expand DJMcMayhem answer to search for the selected words in the buffer like so:

```
:nnoremap * viwy/<C-R>"<CR>Ngn
:vnoremap * wiwy/<C-R>"<CR>Ngn
```

After selecting the correct number of words, it searches the selection with `y/<C-R>"<CR>`, then reselect it with `Ngn`.

Comment: If you want to preserve the previous content of the unnamed register, you can save it and restore it afterward as Luc Hermitte did in [this answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8210/6698).

Comment: @JairLópez Yes, of course, or you can simply use another register if you can spare one. I should have mentionned it.